# Determine script has been ever started (if it is first-time run)

Tags: ruby, file

I want to run config of my program, only when it is first-time started. Can I determine somehow, did my program ever start before? I think I can create file to check it existence, but is there any more optimal way?

Comment: Well, you don't need another file. You could add a marker to the source file, provided the marker is not already present (but I'd rather run my fingernails down a blackboard than do that). Isn't there a direct way to to see if the external configuration has already been done?

Comment: Cary is right. Anyway you need to save this information somewhere. If not in external file or the program file itself, maybe the database or webservice this program connects to? But don't try to rely on the file metadata: on some filesystem you could have something 'last execution' meta in the file, but it will not work on every filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

Make a config file, give an example (perhaps `config.sample`) in whatever documentation your program provides, and if that config file does not exist, you will know that no one has set the config at all.

While this technically won't mean that your program has never "started before", it will tell you that it has not been configured.